# Showing $\sum{|f(x)|}_{x \in X}$ is absolutely convergent under subset conditions

Tags: real-analysis

I am self-studying through Tao's Analysis 1 and am trying to verify a proof I put together for exercise 8.2.1:

Let X be an at most countable set, and let $f: X \rightarrow R$ be a function. The the series $\sum{f(x)}_{x \in X}$ is absolutely convergent iff $sup\{\sum{|f(x)|}_{x \in A}: A \subseteq X, A \, finite\} < \infty$.

My proof uses a little different logic than is given in the hint, so I was uncertain of the correctness (just proving left to right here):

Assume $\sum{f(x)}_{x \in X}$ is absolutely convergent, so $L = \sum{|f(x)|}_{x \in X}$ for some finite $L$. Take a subset of $X$, $A \subseteq X$, where $\exists n' \in N: |A| = n'$.

Because $X$ is countable (by assumption), we can write $X$ as a sum of two sets, $X-A$ and $A$. Breaking up the sum we get $\sum{|f(x)}|_{x \in X} = \sum{|f(x)|}_{x \in X-A} + \sum{|f(x)|}_{x \in A} = L$. (Note: because $X$ is countable and A is finite ($X-A$ is also countable) and absolutely convergent, we can set up bijections $g$, $k$, and $h$ such that:
$\sum{|f(g(n)}|_{n = 0}^{\infty} = \sum{|f(k(m))|}_{m=0}^{\infty} + \sum{|f(h(l))|}_{l = 0}^{n'} = L$)

Because each term in the series must be positive, each summand on the $r.h.s$ must also be positive. So we can write:
$\sum{|f(x)|}_{x \in A} = L - \sum{|f(x)|}_{x \in X-A} \Longrightarrow \sum{|f(x)|}_{x \in A} \leq L$. This means that the summand over $A$ has a finite upper bound. Since this is for a general subset $A$, the set $sup\{\sum{|f(x)|}_{x \in A}: A \subseteq X, A \, finite\} < \infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is correct. Im not sure if you have thought of this and decided not to go with it but you only needed
$$\sum_{x\in A}|f(x)|\le \sum_{x\in X} |f(x)|$$ since $A\subseteq X$ and all summands are non-negative.

If you want to make it more formal, you can do what is essentially the same as what you had. Suppose that $X$ is countable with $X=\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ and suppose that for some $m\in \mathbb{N}$, $A=\{x_n\}_{n=1}^m$. Thus for $k\ge m$, $$\sum_{x\in A}|f(x)|= \sum_{n=1}^m|f(x_n)|\le \sum_{n=1}^k|f(x_n)| \le \sum_{n=1}^\infty|f(x_n)|= \sum_{x\in X} |f(x)|$$